# Can we add panel inside panel to create nested tabbed menu?

Tags: java, swing

I have written one small code to add three panels to a main panel but the code is not working.

JPanel jp,child1,child2,child3; 
    JTabbedPane jtp;

```
public Panel4()
{
    jtp=new JTabbedPane();
    jp=new JPanel();
    child1=new JPanel();
    child2=new JPanel();
    child3=new JPanel();
    jtp.addTab("Child1",child1);
    jtp.addTab("Child2",child2);
    jtp.addTab("Child3",child3);
    jp.setLayout(null);
    jtp.setVisible(true);
    jp.add(jtp);
    jp.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here i am adding this jp to another JTabbedPane which is added in a JFrame.
I can see the panel jp but not the childs (child1,child2,child3).
Please suggest what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
jp.setLayout(null);
```

by

```
jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: You also need to call jp.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER) if you opt for a BorderLayout.

Comment: @Adamski - CENTER is the default if no constraint is given, but good practice to use it...

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thanks for answers,
i solved the problem.
Previously i was adding childs to JTabbedPane and adding JTabbedPane to JPanel and again adding JPanel to the main JTabbedPane.
Instead i added the JTabbedPane which contains the childs to the main JTabbedPane.
This is confusing but thanks for the help.